# How can I use the context provider api and typescript without correcting me all the time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, react-context

The code below throws me the error:

```sh
frontend_1  | TypeScript error in /frontend/src/State/Store.tsx(23,27):
frontend_1  | Property 'test' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '{ test: string; }'.  TS2741
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  |     21 | 
frontend_1  |     22 |     return (
frontend_1  |   > 23 |         <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
frontend_1  |        |                           ^
frontend_1  |     24 |             {children}
frontend_1  |     25 |         </Context.Provider>
frontend_1  |     26 |     )
```

```js
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
    test: "text-string"
}


const reducer = (state: any, action: any): any => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_PUBLIC_KEY':
            return {
                ...state,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

function Store({ children }: any) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

I am trying to fix it for hours but whatever I tried it still throws me the same error. If somebody could help me I really would appreciate it. This example works in plain javascript like a charm so the issue only comes with typescript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `<Context.Provider value={state}>`? Type of context is `{test: string}` but you are trying to pass an array of two elements (`[{test: string}, (...) => ...]`) which won't work. You either need to pass `state` as context value or change the type of your context: `createContext([initialState, () => initialState] as const)`

Comment: I would actually like to use the dispatch function in all children elements. I am new to typescript and I am still having a hard time understanding the full concepts. I really want to push through because it seems that it has some major advantages. However it blocks my productivity :) @Ramesh Reddy solved it for me thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `value` (an array that has state and dispatch) passed to the provider and the type of `initialState` (just the state) passed to `createContext` is different. Just make sure that these two values are the same type.

You can define interfaces for the state, action of the reducer and use them everywhere.

```
interface State {
  test: string;
}

interface Action {
  type: string;
  payload?: any; // update this as you like
}

const initialState = {
  test: "text-string"
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_PUBLIC_KEY":
      return {
        ...state,
        test: "modifed"
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// passing an array that matches the type of context's value
export const Context = createContext<[State, Dispatch<Action>]>([
  initialState,
  () => initialState
]);

function Store({ children }: any) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
}

const Child = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "SET_PUBLIC_KEY" })}>{state.test}</div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Store>
        <Child />
      </Store>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wispy-fast-r2y2h]